# Many-vertex test problems for the simplex method

Tags: linear-programming, testcase, convex-hull, polyhedra

I'm looking for ways to generate test problems for simplex-method linear programming solvers
(A x <= b, x >= 0)
that have many vertices, so (I believe) would make difficult test problems.

There's quite a bit of theory that looks relevant, e.g.
[How many vertices can a convex polytope have?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/127423/how-many-vertices-can-a-convex-polytope-have)
But I don't see how to turn this into code for A b --
I don't need all the vertices, and [Vertex enumeration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_enumeration_problem)
would explode memory anyway.

For example, a 1000 x 1000 assignment problem gives a sparse 2k x 1m A matrix
with 2m non-zeros.
GLPK simplex solves this in 34 seconds -- not much of a test case.

Comment: Maybe look at some LP relaxations from the miplib collection. They should have some degeneracy.

Answer (score 0):

Extended [Latin squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_square#Number) give
LP matrices with 4n^3 rows (constraints), n^4 columns (variables), and 4 non-zeros in each column.
For examples, n=16 -- 2^14 rows, 2^16 columns, 2^18 non-zeros --
runs for 10 hours
in the opensource [GLPK](https://www.gnu.org/software/glpk) simplex solver,
on my 2.7 GHz iMac.

(The
[Klee-Minty cube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klee-Minty_cube),
which was once a difficult test case for simplex methods,
runs in < 1 second in GLPK simplex, with d=200.
Some intuition on *why* some LP problems are difficult would be welcome.)